# A query related to os.chdir in python

Tags: python, macos

I have 2 variables a and b and the following code:

```
a= /user/temp/new, b= test
```

I am using

```
os.chdir(os.path.join('a','b'))
```

to change my directory to test but I am getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "bfm.py", line 50, in <module>
os.chdir(os.path.join('a','b'))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'a/b'
```

But I have test directory in new.

Can someone explain to me how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 2):

```
a = "/some/path/some/"
b = "folder"
os.chdir(os.path.join(a,b))
```

os.chdir(os.path.join('a','b')), look at a and b you passing as string not var.

Comment: If this helped can please choose as answer ?